# Threads/backend in appengine java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to run some kind of Thread continuously in app engine. What the thread does is
checks a hashmap and updates entries as per some business continuously.

My hashmap is a public memeber variable of class X. And X is a singleton class.

Now I know that appengine do not support Thread and it has somethinking called backend.

Now my question is: If I run backend continiously for 24*7 will I be charged?
There is no heavy processing in backend. It just updates a hashmap based on some condition.
Can I apply some trick so that am not charged? My webapp is not for commercial use and is for fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, backends are billed per hour. It does not matter how much they are used: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/billing#Billable_Resource_Unit_Costs

Do you need this calculation to happen immediatelly? You could run a cron job, say ever 5 min and perform the task.

Comment: how can i rund a cron job?Can i access the update the hash table from cron  job?Is yes how?

Comment: Save hashtable to datastore. Using cron: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/cron

Comment: I cannot store them to datastore as they change very  frequently.The entires in hashtable change every 5 sec or so.

Comment: Can i run a backend for around 3 hours without google charging me?

Comment: Yes, you have 9 hours of backend instances per day free. But the problem is they are always-on and there is no way to start/stop them programmatically. You need to use command line utility `appcfg` to manage them.

Comment: Can i programatically start /stop my application?

Comment: I do feel that Cron Job that being configured every 5 seconds is enough to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can too enqueue a 10 minutes task and re-enqueue when is near to arrive to its 10 minutes limit time. For that you can use the task parameters to pass the state of the process to the next task or also you can use datastore.